# Conditional input still appearing in Shiny after condition is no longer met when using `observe()` and `renderUI()`

Tags: r, input, shiny, conditional-statements

I have a conditional input that I want present in the sidebar panel only when a previous input has a certain value. Unlike when using `conditionalPanel()` and if i use `if` statements, the conditional input is created with `renderUI()` and displayed accordingly when the condition is met. However, when the condition is no longer met, the conditional input does not disappear even if the code for the such input is inside `observe()`. Here is a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Conditional input"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
    
      
      selectInput(inputId = "input1",
                  label = "Input1",
                  choices = c("A","B"),
                  selected = "A"),
      
      uiOutput(outputId = "input2")
  
  

    ),
    mainPanel()
    
      
      
    )
  )


server <- function(input, output){

  observe(
    
    if(input$input1 == "B"){
      
      output$input2 = renderUI({
        
        selectInput(inputId = "input2",
                    label = "Input2",
                    choices = c("option1",
                                "option2"))
      })
    }
   
  
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Initially:

[image]

With the appropiate choice in input1, the conditional input2 shows up:

[image]

However, when going back to choice in input1 that no longer meets the condition needed to have input2, such input2 remains displayed:

[image]

As mentioned above, when using `conditionalPanel()` the conditional input appears/disappears as expected, but is it possible to make it work also as shown in the minimal example with some small modification?

Thanks!

Comment: That's normal. The renderUI is created and there's no command to destroy it after that. `conditionalPanel` is the way to go. Or you can get rid of this observer and put the `if` inside the renderUI, or use `req`. And *never use duplicated ids* (you do).

Comment: Your problem is caused by the fact that your `uiOutput` and second `selectInput` both share the same ID.  Hence disaster.  Also, it's bad practiced, and (almost?) always unnecessary to nest observers and reactives.

Comment: Thank you all for  your feedback! I understand better now, and the given answer works as I wanted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that gives you what you want.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Conditional input"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "input1",
                  label = "Input1",
                  choices = c("A","B"),
                  selected = "A"
      ),
      uiOutput(outputId = "uiPanel")
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$uiPanel <- renderUI({
    if (input$input1 == "B") {
      selectInput(inputId = "input2",
                      label = "Input2",
                      choices = c("option1", "option2")
      )
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The `renderUI` returns `NULL` if `input$input1 == "A"`.  Note that I've renamed the `uiOutput` to avoid the clash of IDs and refactored the code to remove the redundant call to `observe()`.  This isn't necessary because the reference to `input$input1` inside the `renderUI` call is all that's necessary to trigger a call whenever needed.